# How to find if button is in active state in ionic app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I have a screen which has 2 buttons. On pressing each of those buttons, I call a function which does some intensive network task. Everything is working well.

Normally when I press one of those button, it calls the function. But if I press that button again, it again calls that function and does same work. I dont want it do call function again if I had pressed before. Only if I press another button and then press this button again, it should call the function.

So, can I get to know the active state of my button before calling the function?

I am new to Ionic, so would appreciate any help on this.

Button code :

```
<div class="button-bar button-bar-full bar-light"
             ng-if="activityLog.enabledChecked && !activityLog.disabledToggle">
            <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-active': activityLog.isUnblockedFiltered}"
               ng-click="switchFilter(true)">{{ 'main.activity-log-blocked-report' | i18n }}</a>
            <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-active': !activityLog.isUnblockedFiltered}"
               ng-click="switchFilter(false)">{{ 'main.activity-log-full-report' | i18n }}</a>
        </div>
```

PS: I can apply some flags and can make this work but want to know if I can get to know the state of button by some api.

Thanks

Comment: You can make use of Angular's ng-disabled property here, right?

Comment: @SAJ . Can you please tell me with an example, how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the button is disabled or not by using the following method

```
var target = angular.element(document.getElementById("#buttonId"));
if (target.prop('disabled')) {
    // Button is disabled
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Hey Jeffrey.. If i click on my button on then in my calling function, i put this check, will it not be always enabled state as I clicked the button? Also, for now , I am getting value as "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

In your view bind the ng-disabled to a property in the controller "disableButton" as shown below and while clicking the button make it true. Then the button will get disabled while doing api call and in completion you can make it false to enable the button again.

```
<a class="button" ng-disabled="disableButton" ng-class="{'button-active': activityLog.isUnblockedFiltered}"
           ng-click="switchFilter(true)">{{ 'main.activity-log-blocked-report' | i18n }}</a>
```